# Do I need the "while" in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-usage

> My wife, Mary, expresses her feelings for me through her cooking,
>   *while* being oblivious to it.

I ask because the sentence sounds okay to me without the "while". But I'm not a native English speaker so I'm not very sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit the **while**, it is difficult to understand the relationship between the two clauses. Our natural assumption with a **being** clause is that it it causative, for example, all three of these sentences have the same meaning:

> Being good at maths, she always gets A-grades.
>   She always gets A-grades, being good at maths.
>   She always gets A-grades, because she is good at maths.

What happens when we add [while](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/while) is that it adds the meaning **despite the fact that** or **although**: this makes it clear that we are describing two opposing ideas, for example:

> She always gets A-grades, while being bad at maths.
>   She always gets A-grades, despite being bad at maths.

This is probably closer to what you intended, since it implies some  sort of contradiction rather than causality. There remains some possibility for confusion since **while** can also carry the meaning **at the same time**, and the **being** still exerts a strong causality effect, so it would be clearer like this:

> She always gets A-grades, although she is bad at maths.
>   She always gets A-grades, however she is bad at maths.

Your sentence could therefore be much clearer like this:

> My wife, Mary, expresses her feelings for me through her cooking, although she is oblivious to it.
>   My wife, Mary, expresses her feelings for me through her cooking, however she is oblivious to it.

The point that you really want to make is that your wife is unaware that she is doing this, and this could be expressed more accurately and concisely using the adverb [unwittingly](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unwitting?q=unwittingly):

> My wife, Mary, **unwittingly** expresses her feelings for me through her cooking,